# how to fix NullPointerException while loading document to Elasticsearch 7.3

Tags: json, elasticsearch, resthighlevelclient

I want to load a JSON string to Elasticsearch version 7.3.

Following is the code i am using for this.

```
    private RestHighLevelClient restHighLevelClient;
    String jsonString="//here the complete JSON string";
    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(cojsonStringntent1.toString());
    HashMap<String, Object> hashMap = new Gson().fromJson(jsonObject.toString(), HashMap.class);

    IndexRequest indexRequest = new IndexRequest("index", "type").source(hashMap);
    restHighLevelClient.index(indexRequest, RequestOptions.DEFAULT);
```

> Exception : 
>   Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
>   at line `restHighLevelClient.index(indexRequest, RequestOptions.DEFAULT);`

If I post the same jsonString via POSTMEN than it is being loaded to ELASTICSEARCH perfectly.

Comment: can you provide your JSON string and your postman request JSON so that I can try myself?

Comment: Seems like initialisation for `restHighLevelClient` is missing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are not using spring(as it's not mentioned), you can use below simple code to create a `resthighlevelclient`.

**In below code, I am reading the elasticsearch configuration from a config file, feel free to change it to the way you read the properties or config, or if you just want to quickly test it hardcode the values of host and port**

```
RestHighLevelClient restHighLevelClient = new RestHighLevelClient(
                RestClient.builder(new HttpHost(configuration.getElasticsearchConfig().getHost(),
                        configuration.getElasticsearchConfig().getPort(),
                        "http")));
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on your sample code, your restHighLevelClient hasn't been initialized indeed at all. Please find snippet of code below how you could solve this:

```
    @Bean
public RestHighLevelClient elasticRestClient () {
    String[] httpHosts = httpHostsProperty.split(";");
    HttpHost[] httpHostsAsArray = new HttpHost[httpHosts.length];
    int index = 0;

    for (String httpHostAsString : httpHosts) {
        HttpHost httpHost = new HttpHost(httpHostAsString.split(":")[0], new Integer(httpHostAsString.split(":")[1]), "http");
        httpHostsAsArray[index++] = httpHost;
    }

    RestClientBuilder restClientBuilder = RestClient.builder(httpHostsAsArray)
            .setRequestConfigCallback(builder -> builder
                    .setConnectTimeout(connectTimeOutInMs)
                    .setSocketTimeout(socketTimeOutInMs)
            );

    return new RestHighLevelClient(restClientBuilder);
}
```

and your impl class uses the autowired RestHighLevelClient bean:

```
    @Autowired
private RestHighLevelClient restClient;
```